# Directory.GetFiles - SearchOption.AllDirectories Does not give files in subfolders (vb)

Tags: vb.net, getfiles

`Directory.GetFiles` - `SearchOption.AllDirectories` Does not give files that are located in subfolders. I'm trying to copy al `.jpg` files from a usb to the computer but when files are located in sub-folders, it does not copy them.

```
Private Sub ButtonStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonStart.Click
    Dim sourceDir As String = ComboBoxUsbSelect.Text
    Dim backupDir As String = FileDestination

    Try

        Dim picList As String() = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

        ' Copy picture files. 
        For Each f As String In picList
            'Remove path from the file name. 
            Dim fName As String = f.Substring(sourceDir.Length)

            ' Use the Path.Combine method to safely append the file name to the path. 
            ' Will overwrite if the destination file already exists.
            If delete = False Then
                File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourceDir, fName), Path.Combine(backupDir, fName), True)
            Else
                File.Move(Path.Combine(sourceDir, fName), Path.Combine(backupDir, fName))
            End If
        Next
    Catch dirNotFound As DirectoryNotFoundException
        Console.WriteLine(dirNotFound.Message)
    End Try
    MessageBox.Show("Done!")
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure it are all jpg files (not jpeg or other formats)?

Comment: you cant remove items from a collection you are iterating - the code gets lost on the next item to process.  Collect a list of files matching your criteria and process that

Comment: Are you sure it is no finding the files and then silently failing to copy or move them?

Comment: Will the subfolder files copy if the backup directory doesn't have those subfolders to copy into?

Comment: Thanks!, I indeed had to collect  a list of files first and the do the copy